# Adding item to Eclipse text viewer context menu

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, swt

I am developing a plugin for eclipse. In this plugin I need to be able to add an item to the context menu in the text editor. So far I have been unsuccessful in this, does anyone know how to add this item.

Also, how do I get a string with the text currently selected in the editor.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the selection part, the question "[Replace selected code from eclipse editor thru plugin comand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233102/replace-selected-code-from-eclipse-editor-thru-plugin-comand)" is quite adequate for your need:

```
try {               
    IEditorPart part = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
    if ( part instanceof ITextEditor ) {
        final ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor)part;
        IDocumentProvider prov = editor.getDocumentProvider();
        IDocument doc = prov.getDocument( editor.getEditorInput() );
        ISelection sel = editor.getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
        if ( sel instanceof TextSelection ) {

            // Here is your String
            final TextSelection textSel = (TextSelection)sel;

        }
    }
} catch ( Exception ex ) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

You can then link this selection with the addition of an item in the popup menu, as in this SO question:
"[How do you contribute a command to an editor context menu in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356798/how-do-you-contribute-a-command-to-an-editor-context-menu-in-eclipse)"

```
<command
      commandId="org.my.command.IdCommand"
      tooltip="My Command Tooltip"
      id="org.my.popup.IdCommand">
    <visibleWhen>
       <with variable="selection">
          <instanceof value="org.eclipse.jface.text.ITextSelection"/>
       </with>
    </visibleWhen>
```