# Grab selected text from Eclipse Java editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor

I'm developing an Eclipse plug-in where upon pressing a button, the plug-in takes the selected text in the Java editor and puts in a text box which appears.

My code looks like this: I got it from here: http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg02200.html

```
private ITextSelection getSelection(ITextEditor editor) {
     ISelection selection = editor.getSelectionProvider()
            .getSelection();
     return (ITextSelection) selection;
}

private String getSelectedText(ITextEditor editor) {
     return getSelection(editor).getText();
}
```

The problem is how will I get the `ITextEditor` of the Java editor being displayed. Coincidentally it's the next question in the thread in the link I posted but it's unanswered :(

Comment: When you say, "selected text," do you mean actually highlighted, or merely the current keyword that the cursor is on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could ask for the `ActiveEditor`, as in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg49285.html):

```
IEditorPart part;

part =
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().get
ActiveEditor();

if(part instanceof ITextEditor){
    ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor)part;
    IDocumentProvider provider = editor.getDocumentProvider();
    IDocument document = provider.getDocument(editor.getEditorInput());
```

---

The OP [Krt_Malta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287282/krt-malta) mentions this [blog entry "Programmatically query current text selection"](http://usayadis.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/programmatically-query-current-text-selection/), which is similar to this other SO answer (written *before* the blog entry) ["Replace selected code from eclipse editor through plugin command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233102/replace-selected-code-from-eclipse-editor-thru-plugin-comand).

Comment: See also SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694748/adding-item-to-eclipse-text-viewer-context-menu with a similar problem

Comment: Thanks :) Just after I submitted the question I decided to give the methods I posted earlier a seach on google just to see if any matches come up. One of the hits was http://usayadis.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/programmatically-query-current-text-selection/ which did exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks and regards,
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add one thing to VonCs answer. The technique he describes to get the selection is useful for all kinds of text editors, not only Java editors as this questions is about. But his solution does not work in the case that the workspace part is a `MultiPageEditorPart`, since that is not a `ITextEditor`.

But in many cases (for example with the standard XML editor) a `MultiPageEditorPart` has pages which are `ITextEditor`s. In those cases you can get the active page from a `MultiPageEditorPart` and get the selection from that.

This can be done with the following code:

```java
ITextEditor editor = null;

if (part instanceof ITextEditor) {
    editor = (ITextEditor) part;
} else if (part instanceof MultiPageEditorPart) {
    Object page = ((MultiPageEditorPart) part).getSelectedPage();
    if (page instanceof ITextEditor) editor = (ITextEditor) page;
}

if (editor != null) {
    IDocumentProvider provider = editor.getDocumentProvider();
    IDocument document = provider.getDocument(editor.getEditorInput());
}
```