# Automatically copy the variables to the clipboard when clicking on them in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, clipboard

Is there any way to configure Eclipse so that clicking on a variable automatically copies the variable to the clipboard? (and ideally should also work with function names)

E.g. if I click like this:

[image]

The clipboard should then contain `patients_directories`.

Comment: This would make "paste to replace" impossible.

Comment: @nitind Not necessarily if you maintain a clipboard history. But yes good to keep in mind, makes it harder.

Comment: I don't think there is such a feature, but what's the point to this?

Comment: @nitind Minimizing keyboard use. I am trying to code as hands-free as possible (moving cursor + clicking is hands-free as I use a hands-free mouse, namely SmartNAV).

Comment: Hmm same question is asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452489/eclipse-selection-autocopy-to-clipboard)

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Thanks for the link but different question (though I also had this one in mind as back up, as I use this in Chrome): the guy is asking copy selection, while I'm asking copy where you click, without even selecting.