# Eclipse show number of lines and/or file size

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way for Eclipse to show the total number of lines in the currently open file, and/or the file size in kilobytes, at the bottom of the screen near the current line/column display?

Is there is a plugin that changes e.g. `77 : 70` to something like `77(450) : 70`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a plugin that does this but you can create your own which adds a **control** item to a **toolbar**.

In the control's class you can extend **[ControlContribution](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/action/ControlContribution.html)** and then you can create a label with any text you want. Look [here](http://random-eclipse-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/eclipse-adding-static-text-to-toolbar_13.html) for a similar example. You could create a toolbar which shows any information you want about the currently opened file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [plugin](https://github.com/chandrayya/chandrayya-eclipse-plugins). Along with file details the selected text will automatically copied to the clipboard check this [Eclipse: selection autocopy to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452489/eclipse-selection-autocopy-to-clipboard/29559722#29559722).