# How to indicate a file has changed after modifying it using IFile

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've been able to successfully update the contents of a file via a popup menu extension I've created underneath the Source menu that comes up when right-clicking on a file.

I'd like to indicate that the file has been changed and needs to be saved.  Right now, the file contents change and save automatically.  I thought the IFile.touch method would cause the file to be in a state where it needed to be saved but I'm not seeing that happen.

Here's my code...

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
    IEditorPart editorPart = HandlerUtil.getActiveEditor(event);
    IEditorInput input = editorPart.getEditorInput();
    InputStream is = null;
    if (input instanceof FileEditorInput) {
        IFile file = ((FileEditorInput) input).getFile();
        try {
            is = file.getContents();
            String originalContents = convertStreamToString(is);
            String newContents = originalContents + "testing changing the contents...";
            InputStream newInput = new ByteArrayInputStream(newContents.getBytes());
            file.setContents(newInput, false, true, null);
            file.touch(null);
        } catch (CoreException e) {
            MessageDialog.openError(
                window.getShell(),
                "Generate Builder Error",
                "An Exception has been thrown when interacting with file " + file.getName() +
                ": " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on help from nitind and this post - [Replace selected code from eclipse editor thru plugin comand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233102/replace-selected-code-from-eclipse-editor-thru-plugin-comand) - I was able to update the text editor and the file shows up as modified.  The key was to work with the ITextEditor and IDocumentProvider instead of a FileEditor.

Here's the updated code...

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
    IEditorPart editorPart = HandlerUtil.getActiveEditor(event);
    if (editorPart instanceof ITextEditor ) {
        ITextEditor editor = (ITextEditor)editorPart;
        IDocumentProvider prov = editor.getDocumentProvider();
        IDocument doc = prov.getDocument( editor.getEditorInput() );
        String className = getClassName(doc.get());
        ISelection sel = editor.getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
        if (sel instanceof TextSelection ) {
            TextSelection textSel = (TextSelection)sel;
            String newText = generateBuilderText(className, textSel.getText());
            try {
                doc.replace(textSel.getOffset(), textSel.getLength(), newText);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                MessageDialog.openError(
                    window.getShell(),
                    "Generate Builder Error",
                    "An Exception has been thrown when attempting to replace " 
                    + "text in editor " + editor.getTitle() +
                    ": " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the file's contents marked as needing to be saved, you need to be interacting with the in-memory representation you want to prompt as needing to be saved--the editor from which you're getting the input.

Comment: OK - I'm new to PDE development...I've been poking around and it appears that `IWorkbenchPage.setPartState` might be the method for me to use for this - does that sound right?

Comment: Um, no. It should need saving if it's actually different than what's on disk.  Is it?  If so, how?

Comment: Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way...I'm ultimately just trying to update some text in the editor and then the user can save or discard the changes if they like...having a lot of trouble finding sample code to do this...

Comment: If you're working with a text editor, it should implement ITextEditor and have a IDocumentProvider, which you can get using ITextEditor.getDocumentProvider() and then use to give you the corresponding IDocument for the editor's current input.  *That's* where you can make changes to the editor's contents--and it will mark itself as dirty and in need of saving just as you want.

Comment: Thanks - that comment led me to dig in the right place ;) - i'll post the code that solved my problem...